# Родительская ссылка должна вести на первую страницу подменю

Tags: php, wordpress, menu

Использую такой код меню в `functions.php`

```
class main_menu_walker extends Walker_Nav_Menu {
function start_el(&$output, $item, $depth, $args) {
    global $wp_query;
    $indent = ( $depth ) ? str_repeat( "\t", $depth ) : '';

    $class_names = $value = '';

    $classes = empty( $item->classes ) ? array() : (array) $item->classes;

    $class_names = join( ' ', apply_filters( 'nav_menu_css_class', array_filter( $classes ), $item ) );
    $class_names = ' class="'. esc_attr( $class_names ) . ' nav-item"';

    $output .= $indent . '<li id="menu-item-'. $item->ID . '"' . $value . $class_names .'>';

    $attributes  = ! empty( $item->attr_title ) ? ' title="'  . esc_attr( $item->attr_title ) .'"' : '';
    $attributes .= ! empty( $item->target )     ? ' target="' . esc_attr( $item->target     ) .'"' : '';
    $attributes .= ! empty( $item->xfn )        ? ' rel="'    . esc_attr( $item->xfn        ) .'"' : '';
    $attributes .= ! empty( $item->url )        ? ' href="'   . esc_attr( $item->url        ) .'"' : '';

    $item_output = $args->before;
    if ( $args->walker->has_children && 0 === $depth ) {
        $item_output .= '<span class="nav-link">';
    } else {
        $item_output .= '<a class="nav-link" ' . $attributes . '>';
    }

    $item_output .= $args->link_before .apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID );
    $item_output .= ( $args->walker->has_children && 0 === $depth ) ? ' </span>' : '</a>';
    $item_output .= $args->after;
    $output .= apply_filters( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args );
}
}
```

Получаю [такую структуру](https://jsfiddle.net/51qszpLu/):

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav nav__top-menu">
<li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a></li>
<li class="nav-item"><span class="nav-link">About </span>
<ul class="sub-menu">
<li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">text 1</a></li>
<li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">text 2</a></li>   
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

Если у родительской ссылки есть подменю то она становится `span`.

Как сделать чтобы при клике на родительскую ссылку проиходил переход на первую страницу подменю ?

**UPD**

Нашла такой [плагин](https://gist.github.com/leoken/4395160). Но он находит дочернюю страницу которая была опубликована первой `function has_published_children`, а в меню положение пунктов может меняться. Т.е. нужна функция поиска не по дате опубликования страницы, а по положению ее в меню.

Comment: С одной стороны можно вместо `span` вставлять  `a` - а с другой, на этом меню может быть обработчик js, и непонятно как он себя поведет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашла рещение [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19113582/wordpress-click-on-parentpage-redirect-on-first-child-page-programmaticaly)

Создала шаблон для родителских страниц:

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Redirect To First Child
*/
if (have_posts()) {
while (have_posts()) {
the_post();
$pagekids = get_pages("child_of=".$post->ID."&sort_column=menu_order");
$firstchild = $pagekids[0];
wp_redirect(get_permalink($firstchild->ID));
}
}
?>
```